# Writing PostGIS query?

Tags: postgis

We have table **foo**

- id (int)
- geom (geometry, point)
- property (int)

we have table **bar**

- id (int)
- geom (geometry, point)

Task:

select **bar** items which has **foo** items in radius of K meters and sum of **foo.property** must be greater than some N value.

Is it possible in one query?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code (also queries) we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own attempt.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format it nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM bar AS b
JOIN foo AS f
  ON ST_DWithin( b.geom, f.geom, k_radius )
GROUP BY b.geom
HAVING sum(f.property) > N_VALUE
```